# Include Menu and ListView in NavigationDrawer at the same time

Tags: java, android, xml, navigation-drawer

I want to include a Menu with 2-3 fixed items, that will never change and below the menu I want to include a `ListView` that I can manage dynamically.

I want to do something like the following picture.

[image]

When I start the application, I always get the following error:

```
Process: com.pigmalionstudios.todolist, PID: 7055
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class menu
```

The corresponding error line in `MainActivity.java` is:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Here's the `activity_main.xml` layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <include layout="@layout/nav_header_main" />
            <include layout="@menu/drawer_menu"/>

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:textColor="#424242"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

And the `drawer_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:showIn="navigation_view"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_drawer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/nav_header_height"
    android:background="@drawable/side_nav_bar"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:icon="@drawable/add"
            android:title="@string/add" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/ToDo"
            android:icon="@drawable/pending"
            android:title="To Dos" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/settings"
            android:title="Settings" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

Comment: did u close the menu??

Comment: no, this happens on startup. I did not call closeDrawer()

Comment: did u close the menu tag in xml??

Comment: sorry, wasn't correctly formatted in the post. Yes the closing tag for the menu is there.

Comment: do one thing comment out the listview part and check whether menu works.. if it doesnt then i think menu background drawable is causing the issue give it some other background..

Comment: @SantanuSur I tried your proposition. I deleted the background drawable completely and commented the listView, but it breaks right in the beginning with the same error message

Answer (score 0):

You do not really have to get a `Menu` in your navigation drawer for the desired layout. Just simply add a header view along with your `ListView` in the navigation drawer.

In my case, I just had to create a custom header for the `ListView`, then added the header along with the `ListView` in the navigation drawer. The process might look something like this.

```
LinearLayout nDrawerListHeader = (LinearLayout) inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_navigation_drawer, container, false);
mDrawerListView.addHeaderView(nDrawerListHeader);
```

The `header_navigation_drawer.xml` looked something like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/navigation_header_color_white">

        <!-- Some other layouts to get the precise view -->

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then implement the action click by finding the right view inside the header view like this.

```
Button menuButton = nDrawerListHeader.findViewById(R.id.menu_button_1);
menuButton.setOnClickListener(...);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried your solution but the app breaks with the error: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams

I copy, pasted your xml code as it is and added a simple TextView in the RelativeLayout

Comment: The error message clearly says that your are trying to assign a `ListView` into  a `FrameLayout`. My code example is a sample implementation.